# $\lim_{x \to 0+}{{x^\epsilon}\ln x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}{\ln x/{x^\epsilon}} =0$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

I want to show that
$\lim_{x \to 0+}{{x^\epsilon}\ln x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}{\ln x/{x^\epsilon}} =0$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
I know it can be easily proved when using L'Hôpital's rule but I'm not allowed to.

I think I can prove that
$1-(1/x)<\ln x<x-1$ for $x>0$ where $x$ is not $1$, but I don't see how it can help.

Comment: Note that $x^\varepsilon  \ln x = \frac{1}{\varepsilon }x^\varepsilon  \ln (x^\varepsilon  )$ and $x^{ - \varepsilon } \ln x =  - \frac{1}{\varepsilon }x^{ - \varepsilon } \ln (x^{ - \varepsilon } )$, so it is enough to show that $\lim _{w \to 0 + } w\ln w = 0$.